# How to accept multiple inputs with Scanner function and the input meeting the if statement?

Tags: java

I'm creating a small project to improve my coding skills. So the problem I'm having is that I have an enroll method, which will allow the 'Student' to enroll into available courses. I put all the courses available in the enum class called 'Courses'.

The problem I am having is how do I get multiple inputs, and for every input if it meets one of the if statements it gets to added to an arraylist called 'enroll'. Otherwise if the user does not want to enroll the user has to type 0, to which I expect the next line to be read.

I think if you were to read my code you'd have a better idea in what I'm trying to do.

I have conducted research on how to get multiple inputs and split it, but that does not seem to work for me.

```java
public int enrolled() {

    System.out.println("The following courses available are:\n" + "1." + Courses.COMPUTERSCIENCE101 + "\n" + "2." + Courses.CHEMISTRY101 + "\n" + "3." + Courses.ENGLISH101 + "\n" + "4." + Courses.HISTORY101 + "\n" + "5." + Courses.MATHEMATICS101);

    Scanner CS = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner CI = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner EL = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner HT = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner MM = new Scanner(System.in);


    if(CS.nextInt() == 1) {
            this.enroll.add(Courses.COMPUTERSCIENCE101);
    } else if (CS.nextInt() == 0) {
          System.out.println("Course added and now exiting...");
    }

    if(CI.nextInt() == 2) {
        this.enroll.add(Courses.CHEMISTRY101);
    } else if (CI.nextInt() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Course added and now exiting...");
    }

    if(EL.nextInt() == 3) {
        this.enroll.add(Courses.ENGLISH101);
    } else if (EL.nextInt() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Course added and now exiting...");
    }

    if(HT.nextInt() == 4) {
        this.enroll.add(Courses.HISTORY101);
    } else if (HT.nextInt() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Course added and now exiting...");
    }

    if(MM.nextInt() == 5) {
        this.enroll.add(Courses.MATHEMATICS101);
    } else if (MM.nextInt() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Course added and now exiting...");
    }
    System.out.println(this.enroll.size());
    return this.enroll.size();
}
```

So it is expected that if the user wants to pick course 1,3,5. Those courses will be added to an arraylist. and should return the length as 3. However, it's allowing the user to input more than 5 inputs, if I was to include 0 as an input (user needs to only 5 inputs, e.g (1,0,3,4,5) or something similar where the returned size of the arraylist would be 4).

Comment: You don't need multiple scanners. Just use one otherwise you are defeating oop purpose. Besides there are 5 `nextInt()` statements. So definitely it is going to ask 5 times. Where are you limiting the user to 3 inputs?

Comment: Typically with a scanner approach like this, you'd pose a question and read the response, repeating until done. It sounds like you're trying to take an input like `1,2,3` which is _possible_ (read in as a string, then parse/split that string into an appropriate format), but it's a little further than you need to achieve the same results

Comment: @Goion I'm not limiting the user, however hypothetically speaking if the user was to pick 3 courses and not pick the other 2, I'd only expect three courses being added to the arraylist

Comment: @Rogue Basically there are 5 courses available,  allow the user to have a maximum of 5 inputs (as there are 5 courses, hence why I created 5 scanners, otherwise it just takes one input (with one scanner)). But for some reason it accepts more than 5, if I'm being clear?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try a different approach. You could ask the user to type the code of the courses they want to join like this:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("The following courses are available:");
    System.out.println("Computer Science 101, Course code: CS101");
    System.out.println("More courses...");
    System.out.println("Type Q to end.");
    String input = in.next();

    while (!input.equals("Q")){
        switch (input){
            case "CS101":
                //add course
                break;
        }
        input = in.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn of Object Oriented Programming. This video [Object-oriented Programming in 7 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTB0EiLXUC8) gives an overview of some major concepts. Of course you need to learn them in depth. Anyways this is how I solved your problem. It doesn't exactly follow all you requirements because of lack of information i.e `enroll method` and `Class Courses`. This is just meant to show you what can you do.

```
// Create ArrayList
ArrayList<String> selectedCourses = new ArrayList<String>();

// Displays all courses available
System.out.println("The following courses available are:\n" + "1. COMPUTERSCIENCE101\n" + "2. CHEMISTRY101\n"
        + "3. ENGLISH101\n" + "4. HISTORY101\n" + "5. MATHEMATICS101\n");

// Creating scanner object
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// Prompting user. This is helpful otherwise the user would just keep staring at
// blank screen not knowing that program is asking for input.
System.out.print("Please enter how many courses you want to select: ");
int noOfCourses = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();

// Looping the number of time user wants to select courses
for (int i = 0; i < noOfCourses; i++) {
    // Prompting user
    System.out.print("Please enter the course you want to select: ");
    String course = scanner.nextLine(); // Instead of creating a new Scanner I am reusing the older one
    selectedCourses.add(course); // Adding courses in arraylist
}

// Printing arraylist
System.out.println("\nCourses selected: " + selectedCourses.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
The following courses available are:
1. COMPUTERSCIENCE101
2. CHEMISTRY101
3. ENGLISH101
4. HISTORY101
5. MATHEMATICS101

Please enter how many courses you want to select: 3
Please enter the course you want to select: COMPUTERSCIENCE101
Please enter the course you want to select: CHEMISTRY101
Please enter the course you want to select: HISTORY101

Courses selected: [COMPUTERSCIENCE101, CHEMISTRY101, HISTORY101]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! quick question why did you create a scanner.nextLine(); after int noOfCourses = scanner.nextInt(); when you could've just left it at scanner.nextLine();

Comment: When you call `nextInt()` it reads the input lets say "5" but after that it puts cursor right after 5 in the same line. So next time when I call `nextLine()` it will just return the remaining line which is empty in this case. However  If I call `nextLine()` after this it will read new line.

Comment: @codeisnotf0rme Yes. Let's imagine this program in real life scenario. You are a student you don't know how many courses you are going to pick. You go to your adviser. Your adviser is probably going to tell you about every course along with description, credit hours etc... Now your program should behave like adviser. For that save all your subjects in an arraylist (This could be of type `Courses`) and iterate over it. As you do so ask user do you want this course. If user says "Yes" add it in a separate arraylist.

Comment: Cont... The reason I gave example is because it is easy to program something if it makes sense on paper. First create a logic on paper and then start coding on an IDE. This will make coding much easier.

Comment: Thanks man! as you can see I'm very new and I love your answer!!, Is it possible to contact you in social media in anyway when I'm having problems? Most of the answers other people give I feel are a bit too complex for me

Comment: @codeisnotf0rme I actually visit Stack Overflow quite frequently. Other than that I use Reddit a lot. I'd recommend you to go to [r/AskProgramming](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskProgramming/). You can find me there and the community is also helpful.